# Vimeo Upload Library for iOS deprecated?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-ios

It seems like the Vimeo-Library for iOS (https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload) has been deprecated.

There are countless libs and examples for php/java/javascript… but none for iOS.

Anybody can point me to a tutorial or a lib that's not deprecated for iOS (preferably for ObjectiveC)?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using AppAuth…

That was painful - the vimeo docs aren't really helpful. But I had some old code from an earlier attempt (before I used the Vimeo-Library) that I got finally working.